# Angular2 - search in array inside of an array

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have an array of `events` and I have a `search()` function (below) that filters through it. Currently it only filters for `name` or `date`. Within my payload I have an array of `tags`, and I'm trying to figure out how to include it in the filtering of this. My current work-around is buttons that re-run the `/event` endpoint with search params which I don't like.

```
  search(array: any[], query: string, excludeProps?: string|string[], dateFormat?: string) {
    if (!query || !this._objArrayCheck(array)) {
      return array;
    }
    const lQuery = query.toLowerCase();
    const isoDateRegex = /\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3}Z/; // ISO UTC
    const dateF = dateFormat ? dateFormat : 'medium';
    const filteredArray = array.filter(item => {
      for (const key in item) {
        if (item.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          if (!excludeProps || excludeProps.indexOf(key) === -1) {
            const thisVal = item[key];
            if (
              // Value is a string and NOT a UTC date
            typeof thisVal === 'string' &&
            !thisVal.match(isoDateRegex) &&
            thisVal.toLowerCase().indexOf(lQuery) !== -1
            ) {
              return true;
            } else if (
              // Value is a Date object or UTC string
            (thisVal instanceof Date || thisVal.toString().match(isoDateRegex)) &&
            // https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe
            // Matching date format string passed in as param (or default to 'medium')
            this.datePipe.transform(thisVal, dateF).toLowerCase().indexOf(lQuery) !== -1
            ) {
              return true;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    });
    return filteredArray;
  }
```

I tried adding an addition else after the `date` finder and leverage a `for()` loop on `item.tags` but it seems typescript doesn't really let you do a traditional `for` loop.

What is the actual method of handling this within Ang/Typescript?

**Update**

```
  search(array: any[], query: string, excludeProps?: string|string[], dateFormat?: string) {
    if (!query || !this._objArrayCheck(array)) {
      return array;
    }
    const lQuery = query.toLowerCase();
    const isoDateRegex = /\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3}Z/; // ISO UTC
    const dateF = dateFormat ? dateFormat : 'medium';
    const filteredArray = array.filter(item => {
      for (const key in item) {
        if (item.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          if (!excludeProps || excludeProps.indexOf(key) === -1) {
            const thisVal = item[key];
            if (
              // Value is a string and NOT a UTC date
            typeof thisVal === 'string' &&
            !thisVal.match(isoDateRegex) &&
            thisVal.toLowerCase().indexOf(lQuery) !== -1
            ) {
              return true;
            } else if (
              // Value is a Date object or UTC string
            (thisVal instanceof Date || thisVal.toString().match(isoDateRegex)) &&
            // https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe
            // Matching date format string passed in as param (or default to 'medium')
            this.datePipe.transform(thisVal, dateF).toLowerCase().indexOf(lQuery) !== -1
            ) {
              return true;
            } else if (
              typeof thisVal === 'string'
            ) {
              for (var i=0; i < item.tags.length; i++) {
                if (thisVal === item.tags[i]){
                  return true;
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    });
    return filteredArray;
  }
```

I was thinking something similar to this but it doesn't seem to be returning anything.

**sample Payload**

```
// collection: events
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59dda4b702ac8332bcb90921"),
    "title" : "Gantt Chart Example222dsda",
    "location" : "Home",
    "startDatetime" : ISODate("2018-01-01T12:30:00.000-05:00"),
    "endDatetime" : ISODate("2018-01-02T12:30:00.000-05:00"),
    "description" : "dsad",
    "viewPublic" : true,
    "tags" : [
        "Gaming",
        "Social",
        "home",
        "misc"
    ],
    "__v" : NumberInt("0")
}
```

My function should be able to match 'gantt' to the title and still show the row. It should also be able to match 'gaming', 'social' 'home' etc and pull this same record due to the tags. It should be able to pull from the start or end date time.

Comment: It's hard to exactly identify what you were trying to accomplish from the code without a reproduction. But anyway, could you show an example of this `array` object showing at least 2 elements in it?

Comment: @amal Added - Thanks for the call out. New to Angular so unsure what all factors of code you need to review.

Comment: Why do you have an if and an else if that both return true?

Comment: @DNorthrup I am not sure how you can expect `typeof thisVal === 'string'` for the when the loop is running for `key=tags`, as it is an array. What `thisVal` do you expect to be matched with elements of `item.tags` array?